# PHP: strtotime returns "nothing" of type "boolean"

Tags: php, strtotime

I have the variable `$EDate`, I used strtotime function with this variable with different values and the result was as following:

```
$EDate = 10-21-2013;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = nothing    and the type is boolean
$EDate = 09-02-2013;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = 1360386000 and the type is integer
$EDate = 09-30-2013;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = nothing    and the type is boolean
$EDate = 09-30-2013;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = nothing    and the type is boolean
$EDate = 07-02-2014;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = 1391749200 and the type is integer
$EDate = 10-12-2014;    echo "strtotime($EDate)";   the result = 1418187600 and the type is integer
```

Can anybody explain this and how to avoid the boolean result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas **if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.**

Your code assumes that the date is in `d-m-y` format, and will return `FALSE` since the month values are incorrect:

```
var_dump(strtotime('10-21-2013')); // no month 21
var_dump(strtotime('09-30-2013'));
var_dump(strtotime('09-30-2013'));
```

If you want to be able to use custom formats, use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-21-2013');
echo $date->format('U');
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/52378)

Comment: I used var_dump and the results      09-02-2013 ==> int(1360386000) 
      09-02-2013 ==> string(10) "09-02-2013" 
      10-21-2013 ==> string(10) "10-21-2013" 
      09-02-2013 ==> string(10) "09-02-2013" 
      09-30-2013 ==> string(10) "09-30-2013" 
      09-30-2013 ==> string(10) "09-30-2013" 
07-02-2014 ==> string(10) "07-02-2014" 
10-12-2014 ==> string(10) "10-12-2014"

Comment: @Mayada: That's expected. Your code assumes that the format is `d-m-y` (because of the separator used). The solution would be to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. See the demo I linked above.

Comment: I think the var_dump help me to do the comparison of two dates.

Comment: @Mayada: Nope, that's not what `var_dump` does. It's used to know the type and value (and more) of an (or more) expressions. See the [documentation for `var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump).

Comment: No it doesn't.  I will try DateTime::createFromFormat()

Comment: @Mayada: Sure. Does the above code produce the output you wanted?

Comment: The problem is, I have date $Today which equal (10/03/2013) it is string. I need to compare the values of dates in database field which stored as a string (m-d-y) with $Today I tried many things like strtotime and format date but every hay has a problem.

Comment: @Mayada: That's exactly what the above code does. It will work for all `m-d-Y` dates. Can you give me an example date that doesn't *work*?

Comment: Yeeeeeeeee, it is solved by using $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '10-21-2013'); echo $date->format('U');

many many thanks Amal you saved my day, I spent more than 3 days to solve this problem> شكرا جزيلا

Also I would thank ComFreek for answering my quesion.

Comment: @Mayada: Glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** This answer does not apply anymore to the question, see my comment below.

Put your values in quotes, so they become a string:

```
$EDate = '10-21-2013'; 
...
```

Your current code does a mathematical subtraction: 10 - 12 - 2013 = -2015.

Comment: I grabbed this values from string database field, so the variable is string.

Comment: @Mayada Can you execute `var_dump($EDate)`, please? (I've just seen Anmal Murali's answer. This should be the actual reason.)

Comment: @ComFreek: It's *Amal*, btw. I think the OP forgot to add the quotes  when he posted the code *here* -- but anyway, this answer is also correct. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Oh I'm sorry that I mispelt your name. Yes, exactly. Happens quite often that OP don't post their actual code or introduce bugs in the posted code.