# strtotime() giving null value

Tags: php, strtotime

I have this string

```
$chktodate = "15/02/2014 9 am";
```

And when I am doing this

```
$timetocheck = strtotime($chkdt);
```

It gives me nothing.

Is it not that the function is supposed to take the string like the format which I mentioned ie 15/02/2014 9 am.

Comment: @Glavić: I don't see how that's a duplicate of this question. In this question, the OP has a string which isn't recognized by `strtotime()` as a valid date format and hence returns `FALSE`. The OP asks how to fix this issue, while the other question discusses about working with future dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: strtotime returns "nothing" of type "boolean"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164923/php-strtotime-returns-nothing-of-type-boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) doesn't understand that format, and hence returns `FALSE`. The list of formats recognized by the parser are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse this format:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y g a', $chktodate);
echo $dateObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2014-02-15 09:00:00
```

For a list of all the available formatting options, see the [documentation](http://php.net/date).

Comment: I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function format()

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra: Can you post the output of `var_dump($chktodate);`?

Comment: `strtotime()` doesn't return `NULL` on error, but `false`.

Comment: @Glavić: Somehow managed to get that wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. It's fixed now :)

Comment: Fixed it.The problem was in the string initially.Thank you so much for your help.Accepted.